# Get what user selected in <selecct> element in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I did on my own for hours, but no solution found.
I have a json object in a utility component

```
categories = [
  {value: "English", label: "en"},
  {value: "Hindi", label: "hi"},
.
.
.
]
```

Populated into category

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState<dataCategoryType[]>(categories);
```

Which then Populate a  element in Search component .

```
{category.map((rec: dataCategoryType, index: number) => (
    <option
        key={rec.value + "-" + index}
        onSelect={() => onOptionSelect(rec.label)}
        >
        {rec.label}
    </option>
))}
```

function  onOptionSelect(rec.label) is in the same utility file, defined like that

```
const [lang, setLang] = useState<string>("");

const onOptionSelect = (option: string) => {
    setLang(option);
}
```

When I do console.log on lang, it is undefined.  When a user select an option I want to capture what was clicked in lang for further steps.  Please advice.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code moving setting state in onChange of select and it should work as you want in this way

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const categories = [
  { value: "English", label: "en" },
  { value: "Hindi", label: "hi" },
  { value: "Italian", label: "it" },
  { value: "Spanish", label: "es" }
];
export default function App() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(categories);
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("en");
  console.log(lang);
  const onOptionSelect = (option) => {
    setLang(option);
  };

  return (
    <select value={lang} onChange={() => onOptionSelect(event.target.value)}>
      {category.map((rec, index) => (
        <option key={rec.value + "-" + index} value={rec.label}>
          {rec.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Here is the working version as well https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-cohen-7fk3zw?file=/src/App.js:0-706

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just had to change your solution to onChange={(event) => onOptionSelect(event.target.value)}.  Thank you for all your help.